# Insert items from MySql through PHP to HTML Bootstrap page

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to match results from this [PHP code](https://jumpshare.com/v/hqAa8zsP9zxOius51ZUX) into this [Bootstrap HTML structure](https://jumpshare.com/v/BIWxCCHtX55rR7qXFCaH).

What I'm able to achieve so far is printing items from database in 3-column layout, but I don't known how to combine this results with/ info my bootstrap html "structure/ table". I think I need to work with "id" and increment it after every "echo" (h4)? But I'm very new to PHP. Thank you for any practical advices.

**PHP CODE:**

```
        // Run query on connection
        $query = "SELECT
                            product.id,
                            product.name as product_name,
                            product.price,
                            product.type
                FROM        pizza_project.product
                INNER JOIN  pizza_project.product_type on product.type = product_type.id
                where       product.type in (1,2)
                order by    product.type ASC, product.price ASC";


        $result = $con->query($query);
        ?>

        <table>
            <tr>

            <?php
           $split = 0;
           $id = $row['id']; // just an idea I think I need to start with

           if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                foreach ($result as $row) {
                    echo '<td>' . $row['product_name'] . ' ' . $row['id'] . '</td>';

                    $split++;
                    if ($split%3 == 0) {
                        echo '</tr> </tr>';
                    }
                }
            }  
            ?>

            </tr>        
        </table>
```

Comment: Visually, this is the result so far: https://jumpshare.com/v/QPrZfS9YeWew0ucIjqRu

Comment: can you please paste the entire code, so I could get a more useful example?

Comment: Sure, let me edit my main question post. Thanks for an advice!

Comment: Oh, I can't add more links as I'm new in the portal (missing rep), but I uploaded it here: http://pastebin.com/6KsRRnkn This will print me products as you can see in top left corner: http://jmp.sh/ohnLUMN And I need to place those names under images, instead of fixed <h4> names </h4>

Comment: How is this PHP code integrated with your HTML? Did you put all this code before the HTML DOCTYPE Declaration?

Comment: All in index.php like this:
<?php
    if (!session_id()) session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head> ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                   

$itemsInRow = 0;                                                                                                                                                        
foreach ($result as $row) {                                                                                                                                             

        if ($itemsInRow === 0)                                                                                                                                          
                echo "<div class=\"row text-center\">";                                                                                                                 

        echo "<div class=\"col-md-4\">";                                                                                                                                
        echo "<span class=\"fa-stack fa-4x\">";                                                                                                                         
        echo "<img class=\"product-image\" src=\"" . $row['img'] . "\">";                                                                                               
        echo "</span>";                                                                                                                                                 
        echo "<h4 class=\"service-heading\">" . $row['headline'] . "</h4>";                                                                                             
        echo "<p class=\"text-muted\">" . $row['text']  . "</p>";                                                                                                       
        echo "</div>";                                                                                                                                                  

        if ($itemsInRow === 0)                                                                                                                                          
                echo "</div>";                                                                                                                                          

        if ($itemsInRow % 3 === 0) {                                                                                                                                    
                $itemsInRow = 0;                                                                                                                                        
                continue;                                                                                                                                               
        }                                                                                                                                                               

        $itemsInRow++;                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

Is this what you are trying to achieve? I will improve my answers if its the right way. This is not tested.

Comment: Does this mean that I need to store in my database also img links and text (ingredients) for every product name/ headline? Then I will use foreach cycle and print one by one (headline, name, text) and put it into Bootstrap html structure?

Comment: But otherwise I think it's exactly what I want to achieve. I wasn't sure about this breakdown with several "echos", it looks smart :)